# Where can I find Cultist Blood?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently found the plans for a [Blood-magic edge](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/bloodmagic-edge) that requires [Cultist blood](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/cultist-blood).

Where can I find that legendary crafting material?

Comment: Hrm.  The title of the dupe is kinda misleading; it's only asking about a single one.  Perhaps we should expand this (or that one) to be a general legendary crafting material question?

Answer (score 0):

You can farm this off of the **Cultist Grand Inquisitor in the Halls of Agony Level 1**. He spawns every time you launch a game.

[Source](http://diablo.blizzplanet.com/blog/comments/cultists-blood-legendary-crafting-materials)